# Linear Transformation - Distribution laws proof

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove that?

$f\circ(g+h) = f\circ g + f\circ h \ \text{ and }\ (f+g)\circ h = f\circ h + g\circ h$

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you already know?  What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: I know that the sum and the composition of two linear transformations is also a linear transformation, but I don't know how to prove the distribution law for  the sum and the composition.

Comment: Hint : the distribution law for maps follows from the distribution law for elements.

Comment: Hint : how do you show two maps are equal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let $V,W$ be vector spaces over the same field of scalars. Also let $f,g,h : V \to W$ be linear transformations. To prove your first proposition let $x \in V$. Then we have by definition that:

$$(f\circ(g+h))(x)=f((g+h)(x)),$$

but since addition is defined pointwise we have $(g+h)(x)=g(x)+h(x)$. Now, combining this with the fact that $f$ is linear we have:

$$(f\circ(g+h))(x)=f(g(x))+f(h(x)),$$

and since again addition is defined pointwise this induces $f\circ (g+h) = f\circ g + f\circ h$.

To prove the second, let $x \in V$ again. By definition we know that:

$$((f+g)\circ h)(x)=(f+g)(h(x)),$$

but since addition is defined pointwise we have that this is equivalent to:

$$((f+g)\circ h)(x)=f(h(x))+f(g(x)),$$

and because addition was defined pointwise again this induces $(f+g)\circ h = f\circ h + g \circ h$.

Now note that the first proposition depended on two things: pointwise definition of addition of functions and linearity. The second one depended only on the pointwise definition of functions, so that it would work even for arbitrary functions.

Answer (score 2):

by the linearity of $f$, you have f(u + v) = f(u) + f(v), $\forall \ u,v$.
Using this you have:

$f \circ (g + h) (x) = f( g(x) + h(x) ) = f(g(x)) + f(h(x))$. Then you have the first law.
The second law is valid for any functions.

Comment: Obrigado Leandro!

Comment: Magina ^^ . Qualquer coisa tamo aí ^^